# Pass this.refs as property in jsx in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass 1 node as a property of another React component like this:

```
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref='statusCircle'></div>
        <Popover trigger={ this.refs.statusCircle }></Popover>
      </div>);
    );
  }
```

But in the Popover, this.props.trigger is NULL.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

How can I pass a node-ref to another React component as property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After typing this I realized it's really not an answer to the original question but instead a follow-up to your request for suggestions in your comment above.  If you really don't believe it should stay, I'll delete it but it's too big for a comment, sorry.

### [Reference material](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute)

You must be using an old version of React, so this may not look right to you at first, but you could track that information using state in that parent component by doing

```
ref={ function ( element ) {

    // at the top of render() put
    //    var self = this;

    self.setState({ 
        circleWidth: element.offsetWidth, 
        circleHeight: element.offsetHeight 
    }) 
}
```

Assuming those values change over time, you'll want to add an event listener for that change (which can be added inside that `ref` setup) and have it run that `setState` again when you need it to re-render.

As for `<Popover trigger=` you'll want to do something to the effect of:

```
<Popover trigger={this.state.circleWidth > 999} />
```

...where 999 is whatever your trigger value would be.  If it returns true, then you render Popover.  If not, you destroy it.  Both situations would be handled inside Popover but will not need to touch that `div`

Of course, good practice in React is to do that comparison at the top of `render()` and place the result into a variable like `isTriggered`.

Answer (score 7):

You've misunderstood the component lifecycle in React.
See here: [Link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)

See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/uzvoruf7/
Open your console, inspect the code for the "Composite" component, and see the lifecycle hooks.

```
var Popover = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<div>This is a pop-over</div>);
  }
});

var Composite = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log(this.refs.statusCircle); //ok, exists.
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log(this.refs.statusCircle); //doesn't exist, sorry.
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref='statusCircle'></div>
        <Popover trigger={this.refs.statusCircle}></Popover>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Composite />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**"refs" come alive once the DOM has been rendered.**

Therefore, it follows that inside that return statement, the dom has not been rendered **yet**, hence the reference is null (or all references are null so to speak).

However, inside componentDidMount, you can see that your references are available just as one would expect.

This is a common error: a possible code smell that needs refactoring. Usually (not always), passing down dom-references is indicative of an imperative thought process and is not the React way. I would suggest an improvement but I'm not aware of your use-case.

Comment: Thanks BluePill. After checking the document I know that refs come after DOM. May be I gotta use the DOM selector instead.

Comment: @haotang A subcomponent should not know about DOM elements of the parents so that the subcomponent is not tightly coupled to its parent. You probably want to fire an event (or provide a callback) that the parent component can hook up and respond accordingly.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thanks for your explanation, I agree. The things is that `Popover.render()` need `offsetWidth` & `offsetHeight` of `<div ref='statusCircle'></div>`. At the moment, I'm passing `trigger=DOM selector` and it's working well. But that's not React-way. Any suggestion is welcome :D