# How to pass the list "key" value as a props in nested component?

Tags: reactjs, list, jsx

(I apologize for the ugly code in advance -- currently refactoring)

I'm making a Table of content where the nested content appear when I click on its parent component.

For my logic, I need to pass the value of the list `key` to its children but I keep receiving an undefined error or nothing at all. I tried to pass the value like this: `key={node2.objectId}` and `keyId={node2.objectId}`

I read the specifications on how to pass the `key` value as a prop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30465651/passing-keys-to-children-in-react-js) and [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)

Yet, nothing works.

Here's my code:

```js
import React from "react";

const TocContent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="">
            {props.TOC.map((header) => (
                <ul
                    key={header.objectId}
                    onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                    onClick={(e) =>
                        props.handleHeaderClick(
                            header.level,
                            header.treepath,
                            header.containsLaw,
                            header.sections,
                            header.secNum,
                            header.objectId,
                            header.id,
                            e.stopPropagation(),
                        )
                    }
                    className="TOC TOCsection"
                >
                    {header._id}

                    {props.headerIndex === header.objectId
                        ? props.headers2.map((node2) => (
                                <HeaderList
                                    key={node2.objectId}
                                    header={node2}
                                    props={props}
                                    keyId={node2.objectId}
                                >
                                            {console.log(props.keyId)}
                          //--problem is here-- {props.headerIndex2 === props.keyId
                                        ? props.headers3.map((node3) => (
                                                <HeaderList
                                                    key={node3.objectId}
                                                    header={node3}
                                                    props={props}
                                                >
                                                    {props.headerIndex3 === node3.objectId
                                                        ? props.headers4.map((node4) => (
                                                                <HeaderList
                                                                    header={node4}
                                                                    key={node4.objectId}
                                                                    props={props}
                                                                />
                                                          ))
                                                        : null}
                                                </HeaderList>
                                          ))
                                        : null}
                                </HeaderList>
                          ))
                        : null}
                </ul>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const HeaderList = ({ header, props }) => {
    return (
        <ul
            onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
            onClick={(e) =>
                props.handleHeaderClick(
                    header.level,
                    header.treepath,
                    header.containsLaw,
                    header.sections,
                    header.secNum,
                    header.objectId,
                    header.id,
                    e.stopPropagation(),
                )
            }
        >
            {header._id}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default TocContent;
```

Comment: You are passing down the entire node as the `header` prop. Could you just not use `header.objectId` in `HeaderList` to get the value of your `key` prop?

Comment: @Tholle I use the header.objectId to save the headerIndex of the component. I use the value in my logic : props.headerIndex === header.objectId.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that you can't read the `key` prop in the `HeaderList` component, right? Why not just use the value of `header.objectId` instead, since it's the same thing?

Comment: I get your point. When I console.log(header.objectId), I get the entire object (8 "objectId" instead of 1). In the first few lines of my code, it works because each <ul> has one objectId. The <headerList/> gets 8 objectId. I guess my problem lies there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resorted to change the structure a bit. Instead of the code above, I opted to render the `HeaderList` component directly in its own component (as a child of itself). This way, I'm able to read `header.objectId` and make the code shorter.

Here's the new code:

```js
import React from "react";

const TocContent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="">
            {props.TOC.map((header) => (
                <HeaderList key={header.objectId} header={header} props={props} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

const HeaderList = ({ header, props }) => {
    return (
        <ul
            onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
            onClick={(e) =>
                props.handleHeaderClick(
                    header.level,
                    header.treepath,
                    header.containsLaw,
                    header.sections,
                    header.secNum,
                    header.objectId,
                    header.id,
                    e.stopPropagation(),
                )
            }
        >
            {header._id}
            {/* // if savedIndex === CurrentParent Index */}
            {props.headerIndex === header.objectId &&
                props.headers2.map((node2) => (
                    <HeaderList key={node2.objectId} header={node2} props={props} />
                ))}
            {props.headerIndex2 === header.objectId &&
                props.headers3.map((node3) => (
                    <HeaderList key={node3.objectId} header={node3} props={props} />
                ))}
            {props.headerIndex3 === header.objectId &&
                props.headers4.map((node4) => (
                    <HeaderList header={node4} key={node4.objectId} props={props} />
                ))}
        </ul>
    );
};

export default TocContent;
```

I understand this is maybe not the cleanest code, but an improvement nonetheless. If someone wants to propose something better, it will be much appreciated.