# Can we pass fake keys to children in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a component and it's running well in local server. But I am getting below warning

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Getting this warning means we need to fix the key index props? as given [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).
below is some snippets of my component code..

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                        <Container>                                                           
                            <Row>                                                           
                                <Col className="col-12">
                                {this.state.client.map((val,index)=>{
                                    if(index == this.state.colaborators.length -1)
                                        return <a href={"/users/"+val}>{val}</a>
                                    return <a href={"/users/"+val}>{val} ,</a>
                                })}
                                </Col>                                                              
                            </Row>
                        </Container>             
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I checked some solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30466299/11360069)

As I told my code is working well. Can we use some fake key props? for example

```
key={fake index}
```

And we are using will this affect in my working code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `this.state.client` ever changes, **don't** just use the index (which is sadly common); see [this article](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) for why and its [demo of what can go wrong](https://jsbin.com/wohima/edit?output). You can only do that with a list that never changes, or only grows/shrinks (and not at the same time), not with one where the order changes (you insert at the beginning, or sort, or...) [More in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

I'm guessing `val` will be unique in the list, so use that as the `key`:

```
{this.state.client.map((val, index) => {
    const href = "/users/" + val;
    const display = index == this.state.colaborators.length - 1 ? val : `${val} ,`;
    return <a key={val} href={href} >{display}</a>;
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lists order is not going to change, simply use:

```
  return <a key={index} href={"/users/"+val}>{val}</a>
     return <a key={index} href={"/users/"+val}>{val} ,</a>
```

It will not affect your code and it will remove the warning.

Comment: If the items in `this.state.client` ever change order, this will not work correctly.

Comment: This can result in some unexpected behaviour. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46735689/3257622) with some great answers.

Comment: Eslint will always advise against using `index` as keys, moreover it's just not a correct approach due to performance reasons.

Comment: A lot of the time elements don't really have any unique properties except for their index

Comment: @mousetail - The solution to that is to give them a unique property, not to use their index. (Unless the list is unchanging or only shrinks/grows, never *reorders* [like adding at the beginning, or sorting]. Index is good enough then. But a **lot** of lists get reordered, and index will produce incorrect results.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is true, but in the many applications I have worked on a list changing order is very rare. I think using index is fine as long as you keep in mind that reordering or deleting elements will not work properly.

Comment: @mousetail - All I can do is refer to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys): *"We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance **and may cause issues with component state**. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an [in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)..."* *(my emphasis)* [This demo](https://jsbin.com/wohima/edit?output) from the article shows the weird state issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I completely agree. Use a proper key if *the order may change*. If there is no easy key to find and the order cannot change you can use the index.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I edited the answer, to make sure no harm will happen.

Comment: @mousetail - Yeah, if the order doesn't change, it's fine (I did mention that above :-) ).